# Enable/disable rotation on Salesforce IOS Hybrid app

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, hybrid

Is there any way to control the rotation of an Salesforce IOS Hybrid app. I'm using Salesforce IOS SDK. I want to have some of the screens allow to rotate and some not. I know we can set it the app's general setting but it will apply across the whole app not into each screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) subclass should override `shouldAutorotate` (returning `YES`) and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` (returning an appropriate orientation mask).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your help again:) I can got it working this way in a native app. However, a hybrid app is just an web view. How do we control the orientations based on the page url?

Comment: A "hybrid" app is one or more native view controllers that each display a webview. You should be able to subclass the view controllers included with the SDK and override their rotation methods.

Comment: Awesome:). I made it happen by what you said. However, webViewDidStartLoad didn't pick up ajax calls from the htmls, I wonder if there is anyway to get ajax calls to talk to UIViewController.

Comment: `UIWebViewDelegate` methods fire only when the request (URL) changes. Traditionally you would hook into AJAX requests by injecting your own javascript into the page, or by using a third-party native-JS bridge.

Comment: Just notice shouldStartLoadWithRequest picks up ajax requests. Maybe we can add logic into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cordova plugin to controll the device orientation for specific view
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation.